# How do I get query execution duration in postgres logs with a custom log format or in csvlog?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get postgres to log the execution duration of its queries, in either a custom log format or the [csvlog format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG)

But I can't find anywhere in the documentation which % tag corresponds to the duration in a custom log format, or which csv column contains the duration.

Where do I find that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration of the statement is not a tag in [`log_line_prefix`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX). It is part of the log message if you set [`log_min_duration_statement = 0`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT), which will log all statements and their duration.

Comment: then how can find duration with csvlog. I ran a pg_sleep query and got output.

2023-06-27 00:14:09.634 PDT,"admin","dev_db",2892,"XX.XX.XXX.XXX:55752",649a7d1e.b4c,9,"",2023-06-26 23:09:34 PDT,12/969231,0,LOG,00000,"statement: select 'abcd', pg_sleep(5)",,,,,,,,,"pgAdmin 4 - CONN:1406201"

which one is query duration. plz guide.

Comment: @usersam That was not generated with `log_min_duration_statement`. Perhaps you enabled `log_duration` by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [log duration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DURATION) it is not a % tag as it will be logged in a different line when the query completes. You'll have to make the association between that line and the query using the tags that you logged.

Comment: in csvlog format , there is one line for one query. how make the association and with which line ?